# for loop wget directory creation error

Tags: bash, wget

As a Ubuntu beginner. I am trying to download links from multiple text files with wget2 in batch. The -P "$f" creates directory name with .txt suffix. Is it possible to ignore .txt for -P "$f". Any modification suggestions.

```
for f in *.txt;do wget2 -i "$f" -P "$f";done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${f%.txt}` expands like `$f` but with `.txt` suffix (if any) removed. Don't forget to double-quote it like you correctly quoted `$f`.

```
for f in *.txt; do wget2 -i "$f" -P "${f%.txt}"; done
```

The syntax is portable, it takes a pattern (like filename generation a.k.a. globbing pattern, not a regex). E.g. `${f%.*}` gives you everything but the extension, no matter what the extension is. Here the dot is literal and the asterisk is a wildcard.

POSIX specifies few features like this. Bash supports them and more. Documentation:

- [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)
- [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: This is the solution

Answer (score 3):

I think the most elegant way in bash is to use [basename](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/basename.1.html):

```
$(basename "$filename" "$suffix")
```

Your script becomes:

```
for f in *.txt;do wget2 -i "$f" -P "$(basename "$f" .txt)";done
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/965072/3056710)

Comment: Did you copy that from a blog? Those smart quotes around `“$f”` will come through to the output.

Comment: Removes quotes. Added source.

Comment: It wasn't the quotes as such, it was the 66 - 99 style quotes that blog software often forces even on code.

Comment: Ah. Right. So the quotes should be there, right. If spaces are present in the filename...