# Using wildcards to do mass copying to slightly different names

Tags: bash, script, sed, rename, wildcards

I want to copy many files inside a single directory. An example filename starts with `error042021.mysite` and I want the new name end with `-dev.co.at.txt`. I think I need a wildcard for the number, because the numbers will differ: `022021`, `032021`, `042021`, etc. (number= Month, Year).

For example this is what I want to do with `error042021.mysite.at.txt`:

```
cp -p error042021.mysite.at.txt error042021.mysite-dev.co.at.txt
```

I don't wan't to use `mv` because the old file should still remain.

I tried:

```
FILE=/srv/www/mysite.at/storage/logs/error/error??????.mysite.at.txt
if [[ -f "$FILE" ]]; then
    echo "$FILE exists."
    cp -p error??????.mysite.at.txt error??????.mysite-dev.co.at.txt
fi
```

Or is it better to use `sed`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few problems with your code.

- `FILE=/srv/www/mysite.at/storage/logs/error/error??????.mysite.at.txt` does not trigger filename generation. If it did, you could get more than one result. There is no straightforward way to store more than one pathname in a variable and be able to reliably retrieve pathnames one by one.

  In Bash you can use an array:

  ```
  FILE=( /srv/www/mysite.at/storage/logs/error/error??????.mysite.at.txt )
  ```

  This triggers pathname generation and allows to retrieve pathnames reliably. Arrays are useful in general but in this case not necessary. To iterate over the results of expansion you don't need an array variable, you can use the pattern directly in a `for` loop:

  ```
  for f in /srv/www/mysite.at/storage/logs/error/error??????.mysite.at.txt; do …
  ```

  Arrays are not portable, using patterns in with `for` is.

  Your `[[ -f "$FILE" ]]` looks like an attempt to see if the file exists. If not the above problem, this would be a good idea. Inside our `for f in …` loop we need something similar because `error??????.mysite.at.txt` may match nothing. If it matches nothing then it will stay as it is (with literal `?` characters). There are few ways to deal with this:

  - In Bash `shopt -s nullglob` invoked before using a pattern will make the pattern expand to a null string if there is no match. In this case, if the pattern is used in `for` like above then the inside of the loop will be executed zero times, as you would expect.
  - Or you can test inside the loop if `$f` is not the literal pattern used.
  - Or you can test inside the loop if `$f` is a pathname to some existing file. In principle this is what you tried to do with `[[ -f "$FILE" ]]`. I prefer `[` over `[[` wherever `[` is enough, because `[` is portable and `[[` is not.

  There may be other reasonable ways, some of them specific to what you want to do. E.g. you can not care and let `cp` fail (possibly silently: `2>/dev/null cp …`).
- `FILE` is not a good name for a variable. If you get used to uppercase names then sooner or later you will overwrite your `PATH`. In a script use [lowercase names in general](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42849/108618): `file`, `f`, `path` ([not in `zsh` though](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/532148/108618)), …
- When parsing `cp -p error??????.mysite.at.txt error??????.mysite-dev.co.at.txt`, the shell will expand each pattern *separately*. There is no connection whatsoever between the first and the second occurrence of `??????`. Assuming the script is in the right directory and the first pattern expands to something, the second pattern will most likely stay as-is (or disappear if `nullglob` is active) because there is no matching file.

  The first pattern may expand to multiple pathnames in the first place. In some circumstances the second pattern may expand to one or more pathnames.

  Inside our `for` loop the source pathname is just `$f` (and we will [quote properly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618)). We need to craft a proper destination pathname. In general `sed` may be the right tool to manipulate pathnames; still in this case the shell is enough, like in [this other answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1637475/432690). We will get the proper destination pathname from the expansion of `${f%.at.txt}-dev.co.at.txt`.

Our basic code is:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
for f in /srv/www/mysite.at/storage/logs/error/error??????.mysite.at.txt; do
    [ -f "$f" ] && cp -p -- "$f" "${f%.at.txt}-dev.co.at.txt"
done
```

Notes:

- I used `/bin/sh` as the shebang because the code is fully portable.
- I used the absolute path when generating pathnames, so there is no need for [`--`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11382/108618) while invoking `cp`. Still I decided to put it there to promote good practice. Even if you choose to `cd /…/error` first and `for f in error??????.mysite.at.txt; do …`, then the string from the expansion of `$f` will never start with `-` and the existence of `--` will change nothing. But if someone takes this code and uses it with a pattern like `??????.mysite.at.txt` then they may really need `--`. So here you are, `--` is already in the right place.